# Azure app service http header url encoded

Tags: api, iis, azure-web-app-service, urlencode

We have a .Net 4.8 Web Api 2 application that is used both on Azure and on windows machines using IIS. We noticed a difference in the handling of http headers on Azure and non-Azure installations. When clients send a request containing an http header containing diacritics (like ë), this header value arrives url-encoded in code on Azure, but it is NOT encoded on the windows machine using IIS.

So a call to the api with a header value `tëst` arrives at the code as `t%C3%ABst` on Azure, but arrives as `tëst` on a windows machine with IIS.

Furthermore, if I directly send `t%C3%ABst` as header value, the header doesn't get "double" encoded on Azure, and it still arrives as `t%C3%ABst`. This makes it difficult to distinguish between `tëst` and `t%C3%ABst` values in a header

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Edit:

I've tested the scenario by creating 2 headers (test and test2, and filling them with `tëst` and `t%C3%ABst` and they both result in the exact same header value on Azure. A normal machine with IIS does not perform any encoding on the headers
[image]

Comment: Has the modification you made solved the problem?

Comment: @TheobaldDu I'm not sure what modification you are referring to. We did not make any modifications, we don't know what to do to solve the issue